EFI and BIOS order reversed
This is my ks file:
firewall --disabled
cdrom
lang ${$.system.locale$}
keyboard ${$.system.keymap$}
timezone ${$.system.timezone$}
network --bootproto=dhcp --hostname=${$.system.hostname$}
rootpw ${$.system.password$}
#if OS.VERSION < 35
authconfig --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
#endif
selinux --disabled
bootloader --location=mbr
text
skipx
logging --level=info
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel

#if .system.bootmode == "uefi"
part /boot/efi --fstype efi --size 200 --asprimary --ondisk vda
#endif

part / --fstype=xfs --grow --size=10240 --ondisk=vda --asprimary


firstboot --disabled
reboot

#if .system.bootmode == "uefi"
%pre
parted -s /dev/vda mklabel gpt
%end
#endif

%packages --ignoremissing
@base
@core
gcc
ssh
wget
curl
telnet
sysstat
ntp
kernel-alinux
%end

%post
mkdir -p /etc/dracut.conf.d
echo 'add_drivers+=" xen-blkfront xen-netfront virtio_blk virtio_net "' > /etc/dracut.conf.d/virt-drivers.conf
KERNEL_VERSION=$(rpm -q kernel --qf '%{version}-%{release}.%{arch}\n')
mkinitrd -f \
            --with=xen-blkfront --preload=xen-blkfront \
            --with=virtio_blk --preload=virtio_blk \
            --with=virtio_pci --preload=virtio_pci \
            --with=virtio_console --preload=virtio_console \
        /boot/initramfs-$($KERNEL_VERSION).img $(KERNEL_VERSION)

sed -i '/PermitRootLogin/d'   /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i '/PasswordAuthentication/d'   /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo "PermitRootLogin yes"  >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo "PasswordAuthentication yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
systemctl restart sshd.service

%end


And,why is vda2 marked as a BIOS partition during the Anaconda installation?

Is very abnormal. Typically, BIOS is the first one.


Is very abnormal. Typically, BIOS is the first one.

Is completely irrelevant. Neither BIOS nor EFI care about the order. EFI firmware will be looking for a specific GUID, not a specific slot#, and in the case of BIOS this partition is itself non-standard – it is only used by GRUB and recognized by a specific LBA (sector#) determined during grub-install, so its exact position doesn't matter so long as grub-install can find it from the GPT.
Placing the EFI system partition first is slightly more tidy and forward-looking if the goal is to eventually (in the future) remove the BIOS partition completely and grow the EFI partition to fill the space (or not).
So if the developers of the Anaconda installer have decided to swap the partitions in a newer release, or have done so by accident, that is immaterial and has no effect on the boot process.
Indeed what's slightly more abnormal is having both partitions at all. Typically the system would have a BIOS bootloader or an EFI bootloader present; it is rare to see both.

Thanks， and this is because dual boot is supported
